# Argparse throws error when using Multi-processing and exe (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, multithreading, argparse

The .py version of the Python code works fine, but when converting the file to exe using pyinstaller, I get an error.

The first thread runs fine, but I think when the second thread/cpu starts, the arguments are not recognized or passed.

I get error like 
`main.exe: error: the following arguments are required: -a/--faces, -d/--csv`

here faces and csv are arguments.

My code is something like this:

```
import argparse

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#ap.add_argument("-a", "--faces", required=True,help="Folder path of known faces to find")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--csv", required=True,help="Use CSV to provide training images?")


args = vars(ap.parse_args())


def main(csv,faces):
  ....

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    main(args['csv'].lower(),args['faces'])
```

Comment: Normally `parse_args` is called from the `if __name__` block, so it is invoked only when the file is called as a script, not when it is imported.  You usually only want it look at the comandline variables once - at the start of the run.

Comment: Also is this `windows`?

Comment: Putting it inside if__name__ worked. Thanks